# android content provider error INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have more than 5 applications on the phone that they need to share data with content provider, and each application install first, must create table and URI, so in all applications I should declare provider in manifest, to give the application authority to initialize provider. But I got Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error, how can I manage this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

> I have more than 5 applications on the phone that they need to share data with content provider

Most likely, this is not a good idea.

> so in all applications I should declare provider in manifest, to give the application authority to initialize provider

That will not work.

> But I got Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error

That is why that will not work.

> how can I manage this problem ?

Assuming for the moment that this was a good idea, you could ship the app with the `<provider>` marked as `android:enabled="false"`. Then, the first app could try to access the `ContentProvider`, and when it determines that nobody else has set up the `ContentProvider`, it can enable its own (see `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`).

So, let us suppose that your five applications are named A, B, C, D, and E. A is installed first. The user runs it, A sees that there is no `ContentProvider`, and enables its own. The user proceeds to install B, C, D, and E, and they all use A's `ContentProvider` to store their data. The user now uninstalls A. B, C, D, and E will lose all their data, as their data goes away when A is uninstalled. The user, in all likelihood, will not appreciate this.

The only scenario in which that is a good idea is if B, C, D, and E are supposed to depend entirely upon A. In that case, B, C, D, and E do not need their own `ContentProvider`, as they can always use A's, and if A does not exist, that is the user's fault.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately I can't manage apps installation order.. Any of these application could be installed first. How to implement shared data storage for this case ?

Comment: @alexanoid: "How to implement shared data storage for this case ?" -- I do not know of a good strategy for this. It is a complicated problem, as the user can uninstall any app in any order. My gut reaction is to *not* attempt to continuously share data, but rather give the user the ability to explicitly copy data from one app to another. You could try to maintain the data in some common location on external storage, one that is not removed when apps are uninstalled, but then you cannot clean up when the last app is uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks again ! in case of the simple text file, can I use a simple approach.. for example File f=new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "someveryvery uniquename.txt"); in order to share information(read/write) between all apps ? Is it a good idea to use getFilesDir() method for this purpose?

Comment: @alexanoid: Only if you are really really sure that only one app will work with the file at a time. SQLite should be a better choice where multiple processes might work with the file at once. "Is it a good idea to use getFilesDir() method for this purpose?" -- no, since that is internal storage, not external storage.

Comment: but how to share one single SQLite database across all my apps ? Currently my ContentProvider is implemented on the SQLite database and now I have a problems that we have discussed above.

Comment: @alexanoid: "but how to share one single SQLite database across all my apps ?" -- put it on external storage. The issue with your "first one in gets the `ContentProvider` plan" is mostly that internal storage is removed when the app is uninstalled, which (done properly) you will not have with external storage.

Comment: sometimes external storage could be unavailable.. unmounted and so one. What should I do in this case? Can I always rely on external storage ?

Comment: @alexanoid: "What should I do in this case?" -- tell the user to unmount their phone, I guess. I mentioned earlier that my gut reaction is to not attempt to continuously share data, but rather give the user the ability to explicitly copy data from one app to another. I wish you luck, but I cannot give you a complete solution to this complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should define provider in every app's manifest like this:

```
android:authorities="com.app.SomeContentProvider${applicationId}"
```

It's important that your provider is unique for every app.